# How can an AI agent make a purchase?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, e-commerce, payment, chatgpt-api

How can I allow my AI agent to make a purchase / check out on a website? (and have the associated privacy/security involved with payment information).

New to developing with AI - I've mostly seen shopping AI agents that give you recommendations and are limited to search or questions, not the purchase itself.

A use case might be e.g. "buy me toilet paper" - and I would want the AI agent to actually make the purchase, maybe within a budget.

I'm currently building my agent with a [Custom GPT](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-gpts) and have added additional knowledge to its context to get started. I thought I could use GPT Actions as these can allow an API call outside open AI / ChatGPT but not totally sure how that would work if my purchase could be on many possible ecommerce sites?

Doesn't necessarily have to be Custom GPT compatible, I just chose that as it was the quickest to get started. Open to other thoughts/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Purchases on a e-commerce site (for example) can be achieved only if you have the endpoints to call in the E-Commerce platform to do the following things:

- Select a product
- Check it out
- Pay it

That said. The answer is: It is possibile only if the E-Commerce platform has been designed to have an API so that it can be used programmatically, that means, at the moment, there is no real chance you can get something like that. Because the only way the AI has to call external software services is through Function Call tools (see ChatGPT [Assistants API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/createAssistant) for example). It understands what you need and it will reply with the name and parameters of your function that you should call in its place to get the answer completed. I mean, you'll return the value of the functional call to the AI and it will elaborate on it. There is no chance that the AI (at the current state) will do everything by itself.